# Uncaught ReferenceError: war is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, reference

I am trying to make a make a simple card game web application.

When trying to run the war.refillDeck() function from the button click I receive the following error in my console: Uncaught ReferenceError: war is not defined

From what I have researched it seems my javascript is not being loaded into the page however I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I have included my javascript and jQuery references in my page head.

The following are snippets of my php page and javascript:

war.php

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--------------------------CSS--------------------------->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Page CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/war.css">
    <!-----------------------Javascript----------------------->
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Page JS -->
    <script src="js/war.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container war">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div id="p1-cards-remaining" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 war-head">
                <h2 class="ht">Player 1 Cards Remaining</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="p2-cards-remaining" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 war-head">
                <h2 class="ht">Player 2 Cards Remaining</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Play Field -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div id="p1-field" class="pf">
                    <p>p1 card goes here</p>
                    <button onclick="war.refillDeck()">Refill Deck</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

war.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var aDeck =[],
    aP1Deck =[],
    aP2Deck = [],
    iTurnCounter = 0,
    aNumbers = [
        'ace',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        '10',
        'jack',
        'queen',
        'king'
    ],
    aSuits = [
        'clubs',
        'diamonds',
        'spades',
        'hearts'
    ],
    oColors = {
        club: 'black',
        diamond: 'red',
        heart: 'red',
        spade: 'red'
    },
    oRanks = {
        ace: {
            rank: '1'
        },
        '2': {
            rank: '2'
        },
        '3': {
            rank: '3'
        },
        '4': {
            rank: '4'
        },
        '5': {
            rank: '5'
        },
        '6': {
            rank: '6'
        },
        '7': {
            rank: '7'
        },
        '8': {
            rank: '8'
        },
        '9': {
            rank: '9'
        },
        '10': {
            rank: '10'
        },
        jack: {
            rank: '11'
        },
        'queen': {
            rank: '12'
        },
        'king': {
            rank: '13'
        }
    },
    iCounter,
    oImageObjects = {},
    oImageBack = new Image(),
    oLastCard;

var war = {

    // used to create each card combination
    returnCard: function (sNumber, sSymbol) {
        var oCard,
            sColor = oColors[sSymbol];

        oCard = {
            color: sColor,
            rank: oRanks[sNumber],
            number: sNumber,
            symbol: sSymbol
        }

        return oCard;
    },

    //shuffle
    shuffleDeck: function (aCards) {
        "use strict";

        iCounter = aCards.length;

        //while there are still cards
        while (iCounter > 0) {

            //get a random index
            var iIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * iCounter),
                aTemp;

            //decrease counter
            iCounter--;

            //swap the last element
            aTemp = aCards[iCounter];
            aCards[iCounter] = aCards[iIndex];
            aCards[iIndex] = aTemp;
        }

        return aCards;
    },

    refillDeck: function () {

        //reset player decks
        aP1Deck = [];
        aP2Deck = [];

        $.each(aNumbers, function (i, sNumber) {
            $.each(aSuits, function (j, sSuit) {
                aDeck.push(this.returnCard(sNumber, sSuit));

                //images
                if (oImageObjects.length !== 52) {
                    var oImage = new Image(),
                        sCardNumberSuit = sNumber + '_of_' + sSuit;

                    oImage.src = 'images/cards/' + sCardNumberSuit + '.png';
                    oImageObjects[sCardNumberSuit] = oImage;
                }
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));

        aDeck = this.shuffleDeck(aDeck);
    },

    splitDeck: function (aDeck) {
        //deal the shuffled cards to each player deck
        while (aDeck.length > 0) {
            aP1Deck.push(aDeck.shift());
            aP2Deck.push(aDeck.shift());
        }
        console.log('player decks done.');
    },

    compareCards: function (oP1Card, oP2Card) {
        var sWinner;

        if (oP1Card.rank > oP2Card.rank) {
            sWinner = 'p1';
        } else if (oP1Card.rank < oP2Card.rank) {
            sWinner = 'p2';
        } else {
            sWinner = 'tie'
        }

        return sWinner;
    },

    drawCards: function (aP1Deck, aP2Deck) {
        var aBattlefield,
            oP1Card = aP1Deck.shift(),
            oP2Card = aP2Deck.shift(),
            sWinner;

        aBattlefield[oP1Card, oP2Card];


        //get drawn cards images
        document.getElementById('p1-field').style.backgroundImage =
                "url(" + oImageObjects[oP1Card.number + "_of_" 
                    + oP1Card.symbol].src + ")";

        document.getElementById('p2-field').style.backgroundImage =
                "url(" + oImageObjects[oP2Card.number + "_of_" 
                    + oP2Card.symbol].src + ")";

        sWinner = war.compareCards(aBattlefield[0], aBattlefield[1]);

        if (sWinner == 'p1') {
            //alert the players
            alert('p2 is battle winner with ' + aBattlefield[0].number + 
                    ' of ' + aBattlefield[0].symbol + ' over ' + 
                    aBattlefield[1].number + ' of ' + aBattlefield[1].symbol);
            // give the winner their rewards
            while (aBattlefield.length > 0) {
                //TODO: maybe use splice instead of push to make more random
                aP1Deck.push(aBattlefield.shift());
            }

        } else if (sWinner == 'p2') {
            //alert the players
            alert('p2 is battle winner with ' + aBattlefield[1].number + 
                    ' of ' + aBattlefield[1].symbol + ' over ' + 
                    aBattlefield[0].number + ' of ' + aBattlefield[0].symbol);
            //give the winner their rewards
            while (aBattlefield.length > 0) {
                //TODO: maybe use splice instead of push to make more random
                aP2Deck.push(aBattlefield.shift());
            }

        } else if (sWinner == 'tie') {
            alert('There was a tie. Press \'OK\' for tie breaker');
            //TODO something if there is a tie
        } else {
            console.error('something fucked up when drawing cards');
            alert('please check console log');
        }
    }
};

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object `war` is inside of `$(document).ready` handler scope.
You can export it to window to have global access.

```
var war = {
  ...
}
window.war = war;
```

Also good suggestion is to add binding inside of `$(document).ready` handler:

```
var war = {
  ...
}
$('#p1-field button').click(war.refillDeck);
```

Comment: Or, better, remove the inline html onClick and bind a click handler within the same scope as the variable, that is, within the ready handler.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn, you are right, I've updated answer with you suggestion. I just add first option cause it could be clear to understand an error.